# Python scripting in 3dsmax

Tags: python, 3dsmax, maxscript

Please where can I find resources for Python scripting inside 3dsmax ? I tried Google but the results I found just discuss the access to the Python engine via Maxscript.
I found a little introduction at http://www.sfdm.scad.edu/ but it's not enough.

Answer (score 2):

The 3ds Max Python API Help should get you started:

http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2018/ENU/?guid=__developer_about_the_3ds_max_python_api_html

Comment: Thanks Hoser, it's a great resource :)