# Maxscript / Python command list

Tags: python, 3dsmax, maxscript

I wanted to continue from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908779/python-scripting-in-3dsmax) - but it already has been closed.

I am not a programmer - I'm more of a basic technical artist who needs simple automatable (is that even a word?) tasks scripted down for the purpose of convenience.

Back when I was still using Maya, Learning MEL commands for maya and their Python counterparts was very intuitive thanks a lot this [command list](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/cat_General.html) site from Autodesk.

**

> Can someone point me to where the Maxscript / python version of this
> is? My searches have been fruitless.

**

I mean I found [this](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-CA89F654-31EC-4F3C-8269-F11FCA167038.htm,topicNumber=d30e25331), but it isnt excactly what im looking for. I just need a command list like in the above MEL/PYTHON link with some good examples.

The problem I have as someone who wasn't educated in programming / coding is very nicely expressed in 2:50  and (further demonstrated in)21:33 of this [video](https://youtu.be/ogWEdS_Qlg4).

Today for example, I am just trying to figure out how to write maxscript's (delete $) or (delete objects) in python - and here I am posting on stackoverflow for a guide to some good documentation instead of directly asking how the syntax should look - out of fear of being branded as lazy and as someone who doesnt know how to do a google search.

Thanks

(sorry about the angst. been having a bad day going in circles)

Edit(1) - **about that other thread:**

I did mention the **Python scripting in 3dsma**x post at the very top of my post. But I am pretty reluctant to believe that the provided link in that topic is the ONLY place, the ONLY online resource for maxscript to python topics. That's why I worded my question here very differently.

Edit (2) - **to elaborate even more:**

Is there any online source (other than what was mentioned in the other thread) that can show simple examples of how maxscript would look like if it were to be written in python. See my blockquote example below.

**in MaxScript**:

> Box height:25 length:25 lengthsegs:1 width:25 widthsegs:1
> mapcoords:off heightsegs:1 name:("tae")

**... would look like this in Python:**

> import MaxPlus as mp
>
> from pymxs import runtime as rt
>
> rt.box (height = 25, length = 25, lengthsegs = 1, width = 25,
> widthsegs = 1, mapcoords=off, heightsegs=1,  name= ("tae"))

I, as a non-programmer was able to find exactly this kind of documentation for MEL in Maya located [here](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/cat_General.html).  And because that sort of document exists, I would assume that such a well organized command reference that has good examples is the norm.

Keep in mind that not everyone trying to learn has the luxury of time, circumstances like employment, deadlines and such can sometimes corner laymen into trying to seek out fast solutions instead of signing up for a degree in programming / coding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python scripting in 3dsmax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908779/python-scripting-in-3dsmax)

Comment: Why ask [the exact same question](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/3ds-max-programming/maxscript-python-command-list/td-p/7761401) you've accepted an answer for already elsewhere?

Comment: because while I appreciate the direction I was pointed to there (thank you Swordslayer) it wasn't really of any practical help for me given the circumstances of my situation. And I only accepted the answer so that the forum doesn't pester me to do so despite me not wanting to.

Comment: the main issue i have with your response there - is really just time. If I had the time and space to sit down and educate myself I would - but I wont elaborate on the constraints that I have going on in my life. Besides - what's wrong with asking / looking in more places than one - it kinda is the whole point of research is it not?

Comment: You don't have to accept the answer and you can ask if anything's not clear to you. I wouldn't call research asking the exact same question with the exact same misleading [links](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-CA89F654-31EC-4F3C-8269-F11FCA167038.htm,topicNumber=d30e25331). Your second edit is much better question - check the sample python files in max root for that.

Answer (score 0):

Some helpful resources for learning MaxScript -

- First, the MacroRecorder.  From the MaxScript listener, toggle MacroRecorder menu->Enable, and watch the output in the upper (red) window area while performing scene operations through the UI, for an equivalent script.  The output can be a little chatty, but it should give some useful hints.  If you delete an object, for example, you'll see one call to `actionMan.executeAction` which indicates hitting a hotkey, then another call to `delete $`, which is what you're interested in.  The `$` symbol is a way of referring to the selected object (or set of objects) in the scene.
- Second, the `help` command in MaxScript.  Add quotes around whatever you want to search for.  To search commands for the "delete" keyword, use `help "delete"`.  It lists out every command containing that term.  In this case, the term is very common, and the results are a bit overwhelming.  But for more specific cases it's a useful way of exploring the language.
- Third, the `F1` key.  Maybe obvious. But selecting anything in the MaxScript listener and hitting `F1` opens the MaxScript help website with a search for that term.

Finally, I agree the search tools on the MaxScript help website are somewhat broken.  The site never seems to return results in a helpful order of relevance.  Which impedes learning, even if individual topics are quite helpful when you find them.  Keep in mind the Autodesk forums are monitored by staff, so raising your voice there will help to raise the priority for fixing these issues.